# how can i get the value of index in listbox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, listbox

I am writing a c# windows form application program on vb. I have a listbox and when I double-click on any data it is removed but before delete it I want to keep the data in a string or integer. How can i do that? 
Here is my code to delete:

```
void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);

    if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());

        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(index);              
    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say, based on your description, but I think what you are looking for is `listBox.Items(index)`

Comment: Interesting - you're writing a C# application in VB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the selected item in a variable like this

```
object selected = listBox1.Items[index];
```

Is that what you're asking for?